# how is this login form on java works without comparing String with the text input, how this code works?

Tags: java, netbeans, linked-list

soo i recently followed a tutorial on youtube about login form in java swing but connected with mysql. when the input ont the text field same with the data on the database(which is username and password ) it jump to another jform. but i dont understand something, the code is listed below.

```
private void loginbuttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        String dataBase = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/laundry_akun";
        String dbUsername = "root";
        String dbPassword = "";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dataBase,dbUsername,dbPassword);
        
        String username = username_textfield.getText();
        String password = password_textfield.getText();
        
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM akun WHERE username='" + username + "' and password='" + password + "'";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        
        if(rs.next()){
            dispose();
            testpage tes = new testpage();
            tes.show();
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Username or Password Wrong");
            username_textfield.setText("");
            password_textfield.setText("");
        }
        
        con.close();

    }  catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**How can the linked list or "rs.next"** is detecting my input and then comparing it with the database? since there is no comparason like example "rs.next==username_textfield.getText()" inside the if ? im quite confused about this. also, *the code works just fine* but i just confused on how it works...

Comment: `rs.next()` is true if the ResultSet has a valid row available, meaning the database query returned something. If the user name and password matches, then this will occur. Otherwise the ResultSet will be empty and `rs.next()` will return false.

Comment: "*`String sql = "SELECT * FROM akun WHERE username='" + username + "' and password='" + password + "'"`*" - I recommend studying this query.

Comment: It doesn't need to compare anything. The query is selecting all rows of a table that contain the username and password that the user entered. If that query returns any results at all, the username and password exist in the database in the same row.

Comment: Strong suggestion: don't use YouTube videos to learn key programming concepts. Use decent tutorials, books or coursework to do this.

Comment: As an aside: I really, really, REALLY hope that this code is not part of any production system. It seems to store password in clear text.

Comment: Another aside: there does not seem to be any sanitization, this means the implementation is prone to SQL injection. This, together with the fact that passwords are stored in clear text is a recipe for a password dump.

Comment: You're probably better off using a [`CardLayout`](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/64-java-login-with-cardlayout)